# Frama-C Value Builtins

Tags: frama-c

I just built installed from the Opam package manager, and am trying to learn how to use value analysis from the tutorial on the frama-c website.  I'm currently unable to use the builtin.c file, it's not in my share folder and I cannot figure out how to use -val-builtin (if that's even appropriate).

Any ideas on how to get this going?

I installed the 20151002 release of Frama-c.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: It appears that the ubuntu package has this file, but the mainline 20151002 release does not.  Just started using the 2013 release in the Ubuntu repo instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frama-C "semi-builtins" such as `Frama_C_interval` no longer need an implementation to be analyzed by Value. Hence, most of `builtin.c` has been removed, and the rest has been inlined in other files. All mentions of `builtin.c` in the manual can be ignored, provided `__fc_builtin.h` is included instead. Similarly, `builtin.h` has been replaced by  `__fc_builtin.h`. (But a warning is emitted to make the user aware of this fact.) We will update the manuals for Frama-C Aluminium to clarify this.

Regarding which version should be used, I strongly advise you to use Magnesium (20151002). There have been quite a few improvements through the years.

Comment: Ahh, I'd found __fc_builtin.h but I wasn't sure if that was the correct file to point to instead.  Thanks!!